# How can I adjust the vertical spacing between citations in the jurabib bibliography?

Tags: vertical-spacing, jurabib

I have a document that still uses the nearly obsolete `jurabib` package, but due to the fact, that the book is going to be published soon, I cannot change to `biblatex` or `biber` which would make a lot of things way simpler.

Nevertheless my document has a lot of entries in the bibliography and I want to space them out more nicely, this is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{jurabib}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@BOOK{Test,
    author = {Test},
    title = {Test},
    year = {2020},
    address = {StackExchange}
}
@BOOK{Test2,
author = {Test2},
title = {Test2},
year = {2020},
address = {StackExchange}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}    
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{literatur}
    \bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

The only option documented to change the vertical spacing is `\usepackage[bibformat=compress]{jurabib}`, but this reduces the vertical space even further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution to achieve this is to make use of the `\jbmakeinbiblist` command by saying:

```
\renewcommand{\jbmakeinbiblist}{\setlength{\parsep}{8ex}\setlength{\itemsep}{0bp}}
```

and thereby you get:

[image]